# Use FIELD in ActiveRecord association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to show posts that are tagged with the current locale first. I thought that the MySQL FIELD function would be a nice way to solve this.

However,

```
Post.includes(:tags).order("FIELD(tags.name, '#{I18n.locale}') DESC").first
```

results in

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'tags.name' in 'order clause': SELECT  spree_posts`.* FROM 'spree_posts' ORDER BY FIELD(tags.name, 'en') DESC LIMIT 1
```

If I try

```
Post.includes(:tags).order("FIELD(tags.name, '#{I18n.locale}') DESC").where.not(tags: { name: 'WTF?' } )
```

it returns the posts according to the FIELD method correctly, but does a join with tags, hence not returning all posts without tags :(

I think this might be a bug in ActiveRecord? It's definitely not the behaviour I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `includes` and ensure Rails loads the table in the main query, you should use `references`:

```
Post.includes(:tags).references(:tags).
  order("FIELD(tags.name, '#{I18n.locale}') DESC").first
```

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT  spree_posts`.* FROM 'spree_posts' ORDER BY FIELD(tags.name,
>   'en') DESC LIMIT 1

There is no `tags` table in this query, the table is not loaded, because `includes` is a smart method, that generates `JOIN` only when included table is used in `WHERE` clause.

You need to explicitly define `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Post.joins('LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.post_id = post.id').order("FIELD(tags.name, '#{I18n.locale}') DESC").first
```

(by default `joins` generates `INNER JOIN`)